# Different arguments per test run with cucumber

Tags: arguments, cucumber

I have the following scenario

```
Given I'm from registered on "Brazil" website
When I login
Then i should receive a ok stats.
```

The Brazil website is almost the same as the US website.
it only changes the url, and text language, but the system is all the same.

arguments works strictly for each country.

I don't want to copy paste this scenario for all countries and I'm wondering if i can have feature/support file so i can replace the "brazil" argument for something more dynamic.

Maybe run like cucumber all tests --arguments "brazil"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cucumber COUNTRY=my_country
```

then you can get value with

```
ENV['COUNTRY']
```

Then you can write

```
Given I'm from registered on what ever country website
When I login
Then i should receive a ok stats.
```

in the step definition

```
  @country = ENV['COUNTRY']
```

and use them like you want

see here

[Passing variables on the command line to a Cucumber test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845606/passing-variables-on-the-command-line-to-a-cucumber-test)

[pass special values to Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Environment-Variables)

The first link show interesting way using cucumber profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing you Scenario to:

```
Given I am on the "Brazil" website
When I register
When I login
Then i should receive a ok status
```

Then you can create a case statement (if in Ruby) in the step definition for each location website. and the other 3 rules can remain global to all the sites.

Or, alternatively you can just use the full URL for the first url and keep the step definition rule simple.

```
Given I am on the "http://www.brazil_url.com" website
Given I am on the "http://www.usa_url.com" website
```

Comment: Still i have to copy paste those steps....  im wondering if i could "Given I am on the "contry" website ...." and that argument i could pass by file or somewhere else.

Comment: see @montells answer, I think that's what you looking for